# Assembly [bx][si] and mov byte ptr how does it work?

Tags: assembly, mov

[image: How does these instructions work?]

How does these instructions work?

I thought that mov al, [bx][si] is [bx+si] but is not that is another value.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean by the equivalence, but `[bx][si]` or `[bx+si]` would add bx and si and use the sum as the address to load or store a value.

Comment: BX+SI = 6; mov al, [bx][si] puts in al 01. How can I find why is 01 and not another value? @BoPersson

Comment: You have to check what is at address 6. To me it looks like a part of the uninitialized `10 DUP (?)`, so probably garbage.

Comment: So that "garbage" address I don't have any means to know it, right? I mean, I can't possibly know it, just if I run the program. @BoPersson